# How can I automate importation and formatting of a text file?

Tags: excel

Excel 2007:

I have an app which outputs several rows, with pipe delimiters, into an ascii text file on a quarterly basis.

```
row example:  NAME|ADDRESS|CITY|DESCRIPTION|AMOUNT|
```

I'm currently importing this file on a manual basis into a blank spreadsheet, using the following commands:

> Data, Import from Text, {Wizard Step 1} Delimited, {Next}  {Wizard
>   Step 2} Delimiter Type = Other = |, Text Qualifier = None, {Next}
>   {Wizard Step 3} Column Format = General, {Finish} {Accept} {File, Save
>   As, FileName}

I would like to automate all these manual steps when opening up a blank sheet.

Comment: Are you in control of the output?  Are you choosing to use pipe delimiters?

Comment: I generate the output file from an SQL table and chose to use the engines default delimiter, a pipe.

Comment: If you switch from pipes to commas and use the .csv extension, Excel should recognize this automatically.

Comment: Some of my data contains commas, so csv is not an option, but pipes are not a problem.. they should've chosen pipes for delimiters instead of commas, since users rarely use pipes.. instead of csv, call it pdf = pipe delimited format :)

Comment: You should be able to escape the cells with quotes.  If your data also contains quotes, then I'm not sure what to do...maybe escape those with `\\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the macro recorder and that remove code overhead .. it is straight forward ..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to import is to define it as a data source.  In Excel 2007 it's on the data ribbon, from text.  This way you won't even need to run the macro again, set the data source to refresh on open and it will update any time you open the excel file.

Comment: First time I've seen this mentioned on a variety of sites... and by far the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already coming from an SQL database (as mentioned in a comment above), add the SQL database as a data source. It will update the data each time (also as mentioned above), and the formatting should stay.